# static method: will they share anything within their scope?

Tags: c#, .net, static

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. For example, if Foo.StaticBar() is called by two threads, will there be anything shared in these two methods' scope? For example, method's local variable, etc.? I know that class variables and properties will be shared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, local variable will not be shared as they're local to the static method you are calling.

The only thing that is shared is state outside the static methods but within the class, ie static member variables.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are private for each call to the method. If the method uses any resources that are declared outside of the method (such as a static field), that resource will be shared for the two calls.